# AndroidDriver is not generic, it cannot be parameterised

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, appium

I want to automate a simple appium script to open the play store app from the home screen. When i try to run the script, i'm getting the following error:

The type AppiumDriver is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
    The type AndroidDriver is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

the dependencies i have installed are:

selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar, commons-lang3-3.9.jar, client-combined-3.141.59.jar, client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar, java-client-2.1.0.jar, java-client-7.0.0.jar, java-client-4.1.2.jar

package tests;

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class AppiumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "RZ8M41XNX1E"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {
                AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have another class in the same package called `AndroidDriver`?

Comment: no, I don't have another one

Comment: [It](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/700) can possibly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only class in your project you need only one dependency: Appium [java-client-7.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0).

You don't need others as they're resolved via Maven's [transitive dependencies mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). In your situation you're suffering from a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) caused my multiple different clashing Appium Java Client libraries in the [Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

So given this *pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>testing.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>appium-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

You will get the following dependencies:

```
>mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< testing.appium:appium-java >---------------------
[INFO] Building appium-java 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ appium-java ---
[INFO] testing.appium:appium-java:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.appium:java-client:jar:7.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.8.15:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:25.0-jre:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.11.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.14.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.141.59:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO]    +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.2.8:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.3:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.10.3:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.801 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-29T15:00:39+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can also check out [appium-java-testng](https://bitbucket.org/kishoreggk/appium-java-testng/src/master/) sample project and get familiarized with [Parallel Tests - Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices) article.

Comment: I dont understand. What am I supposed to do when I get that error?